# Debian, two network cards - "no route to host" on eth1

Tags: debian, networking, routing

I have added a secound nic in a debian box. That nic is ment for doing some test stuff, so those devices connected should just be able to access the debian box or be accessed from it.

To set up the nic, I have added to /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    network 192.168.0.0
```

Those values shows up when I do an ifconfig, and route shows:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         adim.hhv3       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

SO it seems to me as if everything is set up correctly, but when I try to access any of the devices on the 192.168.0.x network, I just get a "no route to host" error. Have I forgotten or overlooked something? (presently I cannot test the other way around. The nic leds are indicating that there is a link)

Things get weirder. I have set up an old wireless router that acts as a dhcp server on the eth1 network. Then eth1 works just as intended - but if I try to set it manually, it does not work. When setting manually, I just use the above mentioned interfaces file.

Set from dhcp:

```
root@sorbus:~# ip addr (removed loopback and eth0)
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:11:95:84:6b:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.142/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth1
inet6 fe80::211:95ff:fe84:6b6c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@sorbus:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.142 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.23
```

And now it seems to work also for the manual setup.... :-/ Good that it works but it would be nice to know why...

(I cannot use dhcp on the 192.168.0 since it messes up my resolv.conf - at least I have not seen any way of stopping it from doing it)

Comment: `route` is deprecated. use `ip route` or `routel` instead, same for `ifconfig` (use `ip addr` instead). `ip route` has a nice option: `ip route get 192.168.0.42` will tell you what route the kernel will use to contact 192.168.0.42

Comment: Thanks BatchyX. I have just been using dhcp for so long that my command-fu has been a bit outdated.

Comment: What does your network setup look like? Specially the net on eth1. ASCII art is fine.

Comment: Could you resolve your route -n output into addresses only (you have the name  adim.hhv3)

Comment: You can instruct dhclient to inject the relevant nameserver into your resolv.conf. On my machine, I have this:   ❯❯❯ grep prepend /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf   
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;

Comment: You can instruct dhclient to inject the relevant nameserver into your resolv.conf. On my machine, I have this:   ❯❯❯ grep prepend /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf   
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;

Comment: My suspicion is that you may have an IPv4 address conflict when using the address 192.168.0.2. I'd be very keen to look at a tcpdump of traffic from the time you restart the network service to the time you get route errors. You can capture that by executing tcpdump -s0 -w route_errors.pcap -i eth1 and then pasting the output of tcpdump -r route_errors.pcap -nnn

Comment: Did you try changing switch port and network cable?

Answer (score 1):

How do the hosts on the the 192.168.0.x network get their network configuration?  If they expect to receive it via DHCP, you will probably need to run a DHCP server on `eth1` (being very careful not to offer it on `eth0`!).  If the devices don't have addresses, you won't be able to route to them.

On my home router I run the ISC `dhcpd` on `eth0` whilst acting as a DHCP client on `ppp0`.  Relevant bits of configuration in `/etc/dhcpd.conf` include:

```
# Don't attempt dynDNS updates
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "mydomain";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;  # This machine

default-lease-time 86400; # 1 day
max-lease-time 864000;    # 10 days


  group {
    # PXE-boot clients
    filename "/pxelinux.0";
    next-server 192.168.0.1;

    host myhost1 {
      hardware ethernet 00:30:18:a5:6b:20;
      fixed-address 192.168.0.66;
      option root-path "192.168.0.1:/export/client/myhost1";
    }
  }

  # Dynamically-leased addresses for visitors
  subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    authoritative;  
    range 192.168.0.128 192.168.0.254;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
    option routers 192.168.0.1;
  }
```

I previously ran `dnsmasq` successfully on `eth0` (I still do, but now only for DNS and not for DHCP).  Here's the old, commented-out snippets from `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dhcp.conf`:

```
#interface=eth0

# read-ethers

# dhcp-range=192.168.0.128,192.168.0.254

# dhcp-host=00:30:18:a5:6b:20,myhost1,192.168.0.66,static

# dhcp-option-force=208,f1:00:74:7e

# dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0

# #enable-tftp
# tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot

# log-dhcp
```